# NLog - It doesn't delete old log files

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, logging, nlog

ASP.NET CORE Using NLog

I have some trouble , it doesn't delete old logs file.

"MaxArchiveFiles" and "maxArchiveDays" did not execute the action of deleting logs properly.

What I do wrong?
Thanks!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog
    xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    autoReload="true"
    internalLogLevel="info"
    internalLogFile="C:\Logs\testProject\nlog-internal.txt">

  <extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore"/>
  </extensions>


    <targets>
    <!-- write logs to file  -->
    <target xsi:type="File" name="ALL"
            fileName="C:\Logs\testProject\testProject.${cached:${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd}}.log"
            layout="${longdate}|${uppercase:${level}}|${threadid}|${logger}|${message} ${exception:format=ToString}" 
            maxArchiveFiles="20"
            archiveFileName="C:\Logs\testProject\testProject{#}.log"
            archiveDateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd"
            archiveAboveSize="104857600"
            archiveNumbering="DateAndSequence"
            maxArchiveDays="3"
            archiveEvery="Day"       
          />

    </targets>




    <rules>
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="ALL" /> 
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

Comment: Have you tried using a different directory for archive?

Comment: Just use this directory

Comment: See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/3846

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current files (files from today) are not part of archive when using MaxArchiveDays. So `maxArchiveDays="1"` will only clean files older than yesterday.

You could consider removing `archiveFileName` and `archiveDateFormat` and `archiveNumbering`, so it becomes this:

```xml
    <target xsi:type="File" name="ALL"
            fileName="C:\Logs\testProject\testProject.${cached:${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd}}.log"
            layout="${longdate}|${uppercase:${level}}|${threadid}|${logger}|${message} ${exception:format=ToString}"
            maxArchiveFiles="100"
            archiveAboveSize="10485760"
            maxArchiveDays="1"
          />
```

Comment: Thanks team!

The problem is solved.

"MaxArchiveDays" is the date judgement time based on the date generated by the file.

Thank you very much for the prompt reply.